# Get list of MySQL tables and run a code for every table

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I have a number of tables in one mysql database. I need to store the table name in a variable and run some code on each table name.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SHOW TABLES`:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb', 'myuser', 'mypass');
$stmt = $pdo->query('SHOW TABLES;');

if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
    $tables = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $table_name = $table[0];
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it.

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new MySQLi (..); //add ur account details here

    $result = $mysqli -> query ("SHOW TABLES");
    $tables = array();
    while ($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()){
        $tables[] = $row[0];
    }

    foreach ( $tables as $table ){
        // do your processing on tables.
    }
```

More info on `show tables`: [MySQL ::   MySQL 5.5 Reference Manual :: 12.4.5.38 SHOW TABLES Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-tables.html)

Comment: you dont need the foreach as you can do this within the while loop but +1

Comment: @RobertPitt; yes you can, but this way you can use the list outside to, for example, send the list to a function as array of table name and like that. I just thought it will be more scalable to write it this way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain a list of tables with the following query `SHOW TABLES FROM db_name`.  See e.g. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-tables.html.

Answer (score 0):

Using this will give you directly the array of tables, without the need to cycle on result:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=mydb', 'myuser', 'mypass'); 
$tables = $pdo->query('SHOW TABLES')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```