# How to print out multiple entries from one MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP for loop on mysql table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707303/php-for-loop-on-mysql-table-names)

I am a newbie to MySQL and I would love your expertise.
I have a MySQL Table as follows:

```
ID | LISTNAME | CONTENTS
1  | LIST1    | Hi,Hello,Sup
2  | LIST2    | Nothin,bad,sad
3  | LIST3    | Bye,gday,seeya
```

and I want to echo the `CONTENTS` of each `LISTNAME`. Can I do this using a foreach() loop? If so, how? 
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this question first - then see if you can try something first - http://stackoverflow.com/a/4707356/30225, but in stead of show tables use a select statement.

Comment: This question is one step above hello world.  The php manual shows you how to do this on any of the mysql, mysqli or pdo pages.

Answer (score 0):

No, only use a

```
Select * from table
```

if you are using php use a while

Maybe a good tutorial is what you need.

http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM table;');
while ($aux = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo($aux['LISTNAME'] . '<br>');
}
```